# Conversion of string to array

Tags: java

I have a string like the below line and this needs to be converted into an array with the help of java

```
["123","123"]["7845760296","yoga"]
```

I tried giving the string to array directly and it gives syntax error. I am new to this and any help would be much appreciated.

why this is being downed? any problem with my question.?

Edit: I found solution in lengthy way but myself.my bad english forgive

input:

```
 String mystring="["123","123"]["7845760296","yoga"]";
```

output:

```
array[0]=123;
array[3]=yoga;
```

solution:

```
 result_from_server=result_from_server.replace("][", ",");
 result_from_server=result_from_server.replace("]","");
 result_from_server=result_from_server.replace("[","");
 result_from_server=result_from_server.replace("\"","");
 System.out.println("result:"+result_from_server);
 String a[]=result_from_server.split(",");
 System.out.println(a[3]);
```

Comment: How are you getting this String?.

Comment: What is the expected result? An array of arrays? An array of lists? An array of some pair object?

Comment: @Mureinik i want this convert into an multi dimensional array.

Comment: @TheLostMind I am getting this from a server php page.

Comment: @Yogamurthy - Show us exact input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a String to CHar Array:

```
public class StringToCharacterArrayExample {

  public static void main(String args[]){
    //declare the original String object
    String strOrig = "Hello World";
    //declare the char array
    char[] stringArray;

    //convert string into array using toCharArray() method of string class
    stringArray = strOrig.toCharArray();

    //display the array
    for(int index=0; index < stringArray.length; index++)
      System.out.print(stringArray[index]);

  }

}
```

Comment: The result of this code is : ["123","123"]["7845760296","yoga"]

Comment: Yoga.. please share the string with which you want to run my program

Comment: String mystring="["123","123"]["7845760296","yoga"]";

Answer (score 0):

String.split splits strings on a regular expression, this expression may be an empty string:

```
String[] arr = "hello".split("");
```

Yields the array

```
(java.lang.String[]) [, h, e, l, l,o]
```

you can create your own algo, but your question is really hard to understand..